# Show array from getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to use the `document.getElemntById` as a "name" of listing array

```
function aircraft(operator) {
  var typ = document.getElementById('typ').value;

  var B738 = ['39.5', '35.8', '12.5', '2', '79000', '2930', 'M0.785', '189'];


  document.getElementById('dlugosc').textContent = "Długość: " + B738[0] + 'm';
  document.getElementById('szerokosc').textContent = "Szerokość: " + B738[1] +'m';
  document.getElementById('wysokosc').textContent = "Wysokość: " + B738[2] +'m';
  document.getElementById('silniki').textContent = "Ilość silników: " + B738[3];
  document.getElementById('mtow').textContent = "MTOW: " + B738[4] + 'kg';
  document.getElementById('zasieg').textContent = "Zasięg: " + B738[5] + 'nm';
  document.getElementById('predkosc').textContent = "Prędkość max.: " + B738[6];
  document.getElementById('pasazerowie').textContent = "Pasażerowie max.: " + B738[7];
}
```

And I can list all from B738 array, but I would like to have more arrays and use diffrent names of listing arrays like `var typ`, but it doesnt work

```
function aircraft(operator) {
  var typ = document.getElementById('typ').value;

  var B738 = ['39.5', '35.8', '12.5', '2', '79000', '2930', 'M0.785', '189'];
  var A320 = ['39.5', '35.8', '12.5', '2', '79000', '2930', 'M0.785', '189'];

  document.getElementById('dlugosc').textContent = "Długość: " + typ[0] + 'm';
  document.getElementById('szerokosc').textContent = "Szerokość: " + typ[1] +'m';
  document.getElementById('wysokosc').textContent = "Wysokość: " + typ[2] +'m';
  document.getElementById('silniki').textContent = "Ilość silników: " + typ[3];
  document.getElementById('mtow').textContent = "MTOW: " + typ[4] + 'kg';
  document.getElementById('zasieg').textContent = "Zasięg: " + typ[5] + 'nm';
  document.getElementById('predkosc').textContent = "Prędkość max.: " + typ[6];
  document.getElementById('pasazerowie').textContent = "Pasażerowie max.: " + typ[7];
}
```

Comment: looks like [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me, can you tell us what is the feature you intend to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly use the value of `typ` *as a variable* in the way you're attempting, but you can use it *as an indexer* on an object.  Make your arrays properties on an object:

```
var myArrays = {
  B738: ['39.5', '35.8', '12.5', '2', '79000', '2930', 'M0.785', '189'],
  A320: ['39.5', '35.8', '12.5', '2', '79000', '2930', 'M0.785', '189']
};
```

Then you can use `typ` to reference those properties:

```
document.getElementById('dlugosc').textContent = "Długość: " + myArrays[typ][0] + 'm';
```

Comment: Great idea to use 2D array, thank you for your help